# Calculating time difference between two differently formated dates

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I know there are million similar questions about this, but I struggle to find the right answer, so I'll appreciate if someone can give me straight answer.

I have some date in string from backend in this format:

```
String days = "2016-12-01T15:43:42.2737987+01:00";
```

my simple day formatter looks like this:

```
private DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
```

I'm trying to get todays date this way:

```
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

and my method for calculating difference in days looks like this:

```
 public void daysBetween(String date1, String date2) {
    Date mDate1;
    Date mDate2;
    try {
        mDate1 = sdf.parse(date1);
        mDate2 = sdf.parse(date2);
        dateDiff = (mDate1.getTime() - mDate2.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        days = String.valueOf(dateDiff);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the problem here is, I can't parse "days" string because, sometimes I get 7 digits for seconds, sometimes 2, and so on... Is there a way to adjust those two dates to get the days difference?

Comment: Use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'" for the date format, this should add 7 fields for miliseconds. If that doe not work use 2 diferent formaters one for 2 and one for 7 digits

Comment: If you don't mind importing a library, joda has good time difference functions.

Comment: The thing with 7 fields or whatever number, i can't know how many of them i'll get... this project i'm working on is already pretty big, so adding more libraries is not really an option if it's not necessary :) ... Is there a way to somehow exclude seconds and this  +01:00 ?

Comment: ditching the last +01:00 will break if you have different timezones. But you can use date.substring(0,18); Also remove the 'Z' from your simpleDateFormat

Comment: @X3Btel this fixed the problem!! easier that importing library :)  tnx!

Comment: It is an error to escape the letter "Z" in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String formatedDays = days.substring(0,18)+ days.substring(days.lastIndexOf("+"));
```

This will make you date string with only the seconds and will have the timezone in it